# Which of the following is a vector potential for $F$?

Tags: calculus

If $F = (x + 2y)i + (3y + 2z)j + (x^2 − 4z)k$, which of the following is a vector potential for $F$?

A) $(yz + 3z^2 − xy)i + (4xyz)j$

B) $(2xy − z/2)i + (x^3 − 2yz)j$

C) $(z^3/3 + 2(x^2)y)i + (xy − 3yz)j$

D) $(3yz+z^2 − x^2y)i − (xz + 2yz)j$

E) $z(x+2y)i + x(3y + 2z)j + y(x^2 − 4z)k$

I thought I understood the theory for this kind of question.  I thought you had to find a function $f$ that satisfies $\nabla f = F$, so that:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x + 2y,\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 3y + 2z, \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = x^2 - 4z.$$

But it's not working out at all and I'm definitely not ending up with any of those multiple choice answers.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: $F$ is a vector so $f$ such that $\nabla f = F$ has to be a scalar. Sure you have the correct question?

Comment: Yeah, I copied it out from a practice final.  Maybe I was wrong about the ∇f = F part?

Comment: perhaps $\nabla \times f = F$? Otherwise your first approach is good!

Comment: It doesn't work though.  When I try to set the components equal to each other it doesn't work out.  Also, why is there no k component in the correct answer (which is D)?  I really don't understand how to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: The question is wrong, the solution has to be a scalar, not a vector. Now if you wish to find scalar solution, you had your three expressions for all three components of $F$. Now, integrate them with respect to their own independent variable that is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x + 2y$, then $f = \frac{x^2}{2} + 2xy + f_1(y,z)$ where $f_1$ is any function of $y$ and $z$. Do the same with the other two and deduce what is in common.

Comment: I figured it out - the question is asking for a vector potential, NOT a potential function.  So you were right to mention ∇×f=F, that's how to get the correct answer.  This link has a helpful example:  http://galileo.math.siu.edu/mikesullivan/Courses/251/S12/vpot.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The vector potential you are looking for is the vector field, f, whose curl is the F given in the question. So you want the vector field, f, such that ∇×f=F. This mean you need to find the vector field which gives

$\partial f_{z}/ \partial y - \partial f_{y}/\partial z= x + 2y$

$\partial f_{x}/\partial z - \partial f_{z}/\partial x= 3y + 2z$

$\partial f_{y}/\partial x - \partial f_{x}/\partial y= x^2 - 4z$